# Update MySQL with API data and sqlalchemy and avoid repetition

Tags: mysql, pandas, api, sqlalchemy

I download forecasting time series data from an API multiple times a day, since the prediction (for the same future dates and times) is updated based on new information.

What would be the most efficient way to upload these data to MySQL: batch csv or sqlalchemy?

I am trying the latter option, that is, to update the database from a pandas dataframe and sqlalchemy. The problem is that I can only 'append' with `df.to_sql`, which creates repeated records for the same date and time.

Is there another way around this?

Here is my code so far, where `df` represents the dataframe with data that should to be updated or inserted in MySQL. No `id` column, since MySQL auto increments the primary key.

**Old data downloaded 4 hours ago (dfold)**:

```
|      Datetime        |       City       |  Temperature_C |
|----------------------|------------------|----------------|
|  2021-03-29 15:00:00 |      Oslo        |     0.0        |
|  2021-03-29 16:00:00 |      Oslo        |     1.5        |
```

**New data downloaded now (df)**:

```
|      Datetime        |       City       |  Temperature_C |
|----------------------|------------------|----------------|
|  2021-03-29 15:00:00 |      Oslo        |    -4.0        |
|  2021-03-29 16:00:00 |      Oslo        |     1.5        |
|  2021-03-29 17:00:00 |      Oslo        |     2.5        |
```

Python code:

```
connect_url = sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create(
    'mysql+pymysql',
    username='user',
    password='test',
    host='somehost',
    database = 'dbname')

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connect_url)

try:
    engine.connect()
except Exception as error:
    print(error)

# dataframe with some data, no index info
df.to_sql('tablename',engine,if_exists='append',method='multi',index=False)
```

Comment: *What would be the most efficient way to upload these data to MySQL: batch csv or sqlalchemy?* [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) statement with IGNORE or REPLACE. And, of course, proper unique index must exist.

Comment: *Old data downloaded 4 hours ago (dfold): ... New data downloaded now (df):* Show desired data states between and after.